# Node PM2 json configuration to split cluster and fork mode based on environment

Tags: node.js, pm2

In a PM2 JSON configuration, is there a way to choose cluster vs. fork mode based on the environment?

Also, it seems like putting `watch` inside the development environment doesn't actualy restart on changes, even though `pm2 status` shows watch is enabled?

I've tried this configuration but don't get the expected results:

```
    "env_production": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production",
        "watch": false,
        "exec_mode": "cluster",
        "instances": "max"
    },
    "env": {
        "watch": ["files/to/watch/*"],
        "ignore_watch" : ["files/to/watch/not/*"],
        "exec_mode": "fork"
    },
```

When I run `pm2 start app.json` it results in `mode = cluster` but I expect `mode = fork`

When I kill and re-run `pm2 start app.json --env production` it results in `mode = cluster` as expected but the number of workers does not equal number of cores.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by splitting out each environment into its own "app" within the JSON configuration file.

Comment: Hi I have  a related question, can you take a look ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73196051/can-pm2-cluster-mode-assign-different-env-to-worker-as-nodejs-cluster-forkenv